# Monopoly Deal Wild Property and paying debts

Tags: monopoly-deal

If a player has a wild property down and is charged a rent, are they able to withhold the wild card?

Specifically, if it is their last card, and they still owe, can it be kept?

According to [this site](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Monopoly_Deal), the wild cards have no value and cannot be used to pay debt...  however, does that mean a player gets to keep them if they owe and cannot pay otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are able to (and indeed must) withhold the card. This follows from the fact that the card cannot be used to pay rent (as you cite) and that

> If you have no cards in front of you worth any monetary amount shown on the corner of the card, you do not pay anything.

(Quoted from [this site](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=payment#question-payment-12))